# Derive formula for Shapley value

Tags: game-theory

I have an exercise for Shapley value. As I know how to calculate it, I have an 8-element set and it would be difficult to calculate it by hand. 
It is a network G(V, E), where V is the set of nodes and E set of edges.

The characteristic function on this network

$$
  v: 2^v -> \mathbb{R}
  \\
  v(C) = |C| - 1/3 \quad N(C)\quad for\quad C \in 2^v
$$

where N(C) denotes numbers of neighbours of nodes in coalition C.
This is the graph:
[Graph picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAzdd.png)

I need to derive the formula for the Shapley value of this game, calculate its complexity and compute the Shapley value for 2 nodes from the sample network.

Would highly appreciate any help - even just a hint where to start.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone was wondering, this could be solved conveniently using https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1402/1402.0567.pdf